# With Vimeo API, unable to create new album even with access token and create scope

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I'm using [Vimeo's official NodeJS API module](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.js?utm_source=recordnotfound.com) to build an app, and I can successfully upload a video without issue.  I can also set the video's privacy property successfully.  Now, I would like to move that uploaded video to an album, and if the album does not exist, I want to create one automatically.  I have an access token stored in a file that my application reads from, and the scopes granted to the token are the following

`"scope": "interact create edit upload delete video_files private public"`

So, I've got the `create` scope which is needed to create a new album for a user.  However, when I make the request to the Vimeo API, I am getting an error of which I cannot resolve or fix.

```
{
  "invalid_parameters":[{
      "field":"name",
      "error_code":2204,
      "error":"You have provided an invalid parameter. Please contact developer of this application.",
      "developer_message":"The parameters passed to this API endpoint did not pass Vimeo's validation. Please check the invalid_parameters list for more information."
  }]
}
```

Here is my code that is making the request:

```
if (!album_uri) {

    console.log("Attempting to create a new album named `" + config.params.video.group + "`");

    var req_make_album = {
                            "method"        : "POST"
                          , "path"          : "/me/albums"
                          , "name"          : config.params.video.group
                          , "description"   : config.params.video.group
                        };

    api.request(req_make_album, function(error, body, status_code, headers) {

                if (error)
                   throw new Error(error);

                step();

     })
```

}

To be sure, the `config.params.video.group` variable is a string and to be certain that it was in fact a string, I replaced the request options with literal ones as such:

```
var req_make_album = {
                         "method"        : "POST"
                       , "path"          : "/me/albums"
                       , "name"          : "My First New Album"
                       , "description"   : "My First New Album"
                     };
```

Still, I received the above error about the `"name"` field being invalid.  What am I missing here?  When I go to the Vimeo API "playground" for this particular endpoint, it does work (even when I authenticate via my app) but I don't understand why it won't work when I make the request via the NodeJS module.  Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake.  The issue is that the Vimeo API requires that the items `"name"` and `"description"` to be passed as an object.

So, instead of

```
var req_make_album = {
                         "method"        : "POST"
                       , "path"          : "/me/albums"
                       , "name"          : "My First New Album"
                       , "description"   : "My First New Album"
                     };
```

It should actually be:

```
var req_make_album = {
                         "method"        : "POST"
                       , "path"          : "/me/albums"
                       , "query"         : {"name" : "My First New Album", "description" : "My First Album's Description"
                     };
```

The more you know :)